# Why is my counter incrementing by 3's instead of 1's (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, html, arraylist

I am building a blackjack game, and for every win, loss or draw their respective number should increase by... but in my code its either incrementing by 2 or 3. I can't figure out why. My code is below:

```
   let blackjackGame = {

    'you': {'scoreSpan': '#your-blackjack-result', 'div': '#your-box', 'score':0},
    'dealer': {'scoreSpan': '#dealer-blackjack-result', 'div': '#dealer-box', 'score':0},
    'cards': ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'K', 'J', 'Q', 'A'],
    'cardsMap': {'2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, '10':10, 'K':10, 'J':10, 'Q':10, 'A':[1, 11]},
    'wins': 0,
    'losses': 0,
    'draws': 0,
};


const YOU = blackjackGame['you'];
const DEALER = blackjackGame['dealer'];



document.querySelector('#blackjack-hit-button').addEventListener('click', blackjackHit);

document.querySelector('#blackjack-stand-button').addEventListener('click', dealerLogic );

document.querySelector('#blackjack-deal-button').addEventListener('click', blackjackDeal);
```

Every time I click the hit button, these operations happen:

```
function blackjackHit() {
    let card =randomCard();
    showCard(card, YOU);  
    updateScore (card, YOU);
    showScore(YOU);
}
```

Every time I press the button dealer, these operations happen:

```
function dealerLogic(){
    let card = randomCard();
    showCard(card, DEALER);
    updateScore(card, DEALER)
    showScore(DEALER);
    computeWinner();

    if (DEALER['score'] > 15) {
        let winner = computeWinner();
        showResult(winner);
    }
}

// Compute winner and return who won
```

Here is where wins, losses and draws are supposed to be incremented. With "++"

```
function computeWinner(){
    let winner;

    if(YOU['score'] <= 21) {


        // condtion: higer score than dealer or when dealer busts but you're 21 or under.
        if (YOU ['score'] > DEALER['score'] || (DEALER['score'] > 21)){
            blackjackGame['wins']++;
            winner = YOU;

            } else if (YOU['score'] < DEALER['score']){
                blackjackGame['losses']++;
                winner = DEALER;
            } else if (YOU['score'] === DEALER['score']){
                blackjackGame['draws']++;
                }
    // condition: when user busts but dealer doesn't
} else if (YOU['score'] > 21 && DEALER['score'] <=21){
    blackjackGame['losses']++;
    winner = DEALER;

        // condition: when you and the dealer bust
} else if (YOU ['score'] >21 && DEALER['score'] > 21){
    blackjackGame['draws']++;
}

console.log(blackjackGame); 
return winner;
```

}

Where I am adding the wins, losses and draws into their respective divs.

```
function showResult (winner){


    if (winner === YOU){
        document.querySelector('#wins').textContent = blackjackGame['wins'];



    } else if (winner === DEALER){
        document.querySelector('#losses').textContent = blackjackGame['losses'];


    } else {
        document.querySelector('#draws').textContent = blackjackGame['draws'];

    }
```

}

Comment: you're potentially calling `computeWinner` twice in `dealerLogic`

Comment: by the way *when you and the dealer bust* can never happen in blackjack ... if you bust you lose immediately, regardless.

Comment: To the point, code provided, and even a code summary. Thanks for asking your question well, @Owen. @Jaromanda is right. You're double incrementing because you are sometimes calling `computeWinner` twice in `dealerLogic`. Once before the if statement and once after.